# Android parsing ints efficiency

Tags: android, performance, debugging

I am trying to parse some unsigned integers from a file stored on the memory card.
Since java does not provide unsigned types I use longs to store the obtained values.

The performance seems to be influenced by the Debugger:
Without the debugger connected I can parse 20000 values in ~820ms.
With the debugger ~5800ms (on HTC Desire).

Can you reproduce this on your devices? Any clue why the debugger has such an overhead?

Here is the code:

```
public class IntParsingTest extends Activity {

public static final String TEST_FILE = "yourfile";
public static final int LOOPS = 20000; 

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        Toast.makeText(IntParsingTest.this, (CharSequence) msg.obj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Message m = new Message();
                File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File f = new File(path, TEST_FILE);
                long startTime = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
                try {
                    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
                    for (int i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++) {
                        readUnsignedInt(is);
                    }
                    long total = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    m.obj = "Time to parse\r\n"
                        + LOOPS 
                        + " unsigned integers:\r\n" 
                        + total + " ms";
                    handler.sendMessage(m);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    m.obj = e.getMessage();
                    handler.sendMessage(m);
                }


            }
        };
        new Thread(r).start();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public static long readUnsignedInt(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    long b1 = input.read();
    long b2 = input.read();
    long b3 = input.read();
    long b4 = input.read();
    return (b1 << 24) + (b2 << 16) + (b3 << 8) + b4;
}
```

}

**Edit:** It is also interesting that only the shift opperations are slow. If I return one of the bytes or a sum of them it works much faster. It may be the way shift is implemented !?

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed a similar thing. I was doing some bitmap manipulation; took on average 1.3 seconds to process while running on the device, took around 27 seconds with the debugger attached.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here - with debugger connected JVM cannot do just-in-time compilation; to be able to detect breakpoints it has to do bytecode interpretation all the time. Debugger also connects to device log stream, which may cause some overhead.